# Access VBA SQL Update command

Tags: sql, xml, vba, ms-access

I'm pretty new to ACCESS and VBA. But i got a function that parse a XML string to text that i get from a page when pressing a button in ACCESS:

And i want to update this string i get back into a table. But i can't get it to work.

This is part of the code:

```
Set Elomrade = objDocXML.getElementsByTagName("elomrade").Item(0)
Set Natagare = objDocXML.getElementsByTagName("natagare").Item(0)
Set NatomradeNamn = objDocXML.getElementsByTagName("natomradeNamn").Item(0)
Set NatomradeBeteckning = objDocXML.getElementsByTagName("natomradeBeteckning").Item(0)
Set EdielID = objDocXML.getElementsByTagName("EdielID").Item(0)
Set Latitud = objDocXML.getElementsByTagName("latitud").Item(0)
Set Longitud = objDocXML.getElementsByTagName("longitud").Item(0)


Dim str As String
    str = str + "elomrade: " + Elomrade.Text + vbNewLine
    str = str + "natagare: " + Natagare.Text + vbNewLine
    str = str + "natomradeNamn: " + NatomradeNamn.Text + vbNewLine
    str = str + "natomradeBeteckning: " + NatomradeBeteckning.Text + vbNewLine
    str = str + "EdielID: " + EdielID.Text + vbNewLine
    str = str + "Latitud: " + Latitud.Text + vbNewLine
    str = str + "Longitud: " + Longitud.Text + vbNewLine 
MsgBox str


 Set db = CurrentDb()
 db.OpenRecordset ("Nätdata")

Dim NatBet As String
   NatBet = NatomradeBeteckning.Text


Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE Nätdata SET NatomradeBeteckning = NatBet"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

I get the parse to work but not the update function.

Error message: Too Few Parameters. Expected 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Nätdata SET NatomradeBeteckning = '" & NatBet & "'"
```